# Normal subgroups of fuchsian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

This must have been known to the ancients, but I am having some trouble finding the references: what can be said (especially geometrically) about the normal closure of an element in a surface group? Especially an elliptic element (in an orbifold group)...

Comment: @Igor: what do you want to know about these subgroups? They are typically free products of cyclic groups generated by the conjugates of the element. 

Comment: @Mark: what you say is already (a) interesting and (b) not obvious to me. Why is that true? For a torsion-free surface group, since the abelianization is 1-dimensional, the normal closure is of infinite index, hence infinitely generated free, but it is not clear what the canonical generators are (are all the $a g a^{-1}$ the free generators?) and with torsion that is less clear. Plus, if you look at the quotient by the normal closure, do you get something interesting?

Comment: @Igor: By a theorem of Delzant for every element $g$ of a torsion-free hyperbolic group $G$ the normal closure of some power $g^n$ is freely generated by conjugates $hg^nh^{-1}$. I think that in the case of surface groups $n$ should be 1. Every torsion-free hyperbolic group is SQ-universal by Olshanskii. The proof implies that every 1-related group embeds into the quotient you described. In fact if you take "any random" free subgroup $F$ of the surface group $S$, and every element $r$ in $F$, then $F/\ll r\gg$ naturally embeds into $S/\ll r\gg$.

Comment: @Igor: Delzant, Thomas(F-STRAS-I)
Sous-groupes distingués et quotients des groupes hyperboliques. (French) [Distinguished subgroups and quotients of hyperbolic groups] 
Duke Math. J. 83 (1996), no. 3, 661–682. - the paper by Delzant. 

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for the reference! I looked briefly at the paper, and if I understand correctly, the family of elements $h g^n h^{-1}$ always satisfies the small cancelation condition for $n$ large enough. That's not quite satisfying (since one can always get this kind of result by ping-pong in groups which are themselves very far from free (eg, lattices in higher rank lie groups). If you can actually get $n=1,$ that's a different matter entirely....

Comment: Your statement about small cancelation  is not quite true since $h_1g^nh_1^{-1}$ and $h_1h_2g^nh_2^{-1}h_1^{-1}$ have a common prefix $h_1$. The ping-pong in the hyperbolic plane is much easier to arrange than in an arbitrary hyperbolic group. That is why I think in the case of surface groups $n$ should be 1. 

Comment: @Mark: I believe the statement (about surface groups), I just don't see an argument just yet. Presumably for torsion you should get an infinite free product of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{kZ}\dots$

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't say much about the elliptic case, but there is Hempel's theorem that the normal closure of an element $\alpha$ contains a (power of a) simple curve $\beta$ if and only $\alpha$ is a (power of a) simple curve.  Furthermore, any such $\beta$ is either a power of $\alpha$ or a commutator of $\alpha$ with a simple loop $\gamma$ intersecting $\alpha$ in one point.

You should be able to glean some structural information about the normal closure from his paper.

John Hempel, [One-relator surface groups, Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society (1990), 108: 467-474](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2093512)

Comment: @Richard: thanks, I saw that paper (and there is a sequel by Jim Howie), but I am not quite sure yet what to make of it...

 

Comment: Sure thing.  If you're interested in this kind of topological statement, there is also a theorem of Maskit that the covering corresponding to $\langle \langle \alpha \rangle \rangle$ is planar.